# How to handle a git workflow mixed with SFTP and remote changes at the same time?

Tags: git, deployment, sftp, dev-to-production

I have a dev machine and a remote test server.

The dev machine will commit files A + B + C and has already sent files A and C to the test server via SFTP (in my editor). A and C have been modified since the last commit but may or may not have been modified since the upload.

The test server has both unstaged (files A + Y) and untracked modifications (files C + Z) that I don't want to stage or commit.

I usually manually do `git checkout A` and `rm Y` on the test server (undo all SFTP modifications since last commit), and then pull the commit. Then we have the same A + B files on the dev machine.

How could we do this with commands where we don't need to specify the exact files to checkout/rm on the test server, in a real life scenario where there could be more files to checkout/rm before pull ?

This workflow has the advantage of keeping a git history clean while keeping the test server up to date with the files I'm editing.

--- beginning of solution ---

```
git fetch
cd `git rev-parse --show-toplevel`

git diff --name-only origin/mybranch..origin/mybranch~1|cat
// for each x in last output: rm x; git co x

git stash
git pull --rebase
git stash pop
```

Answer (score 2):

Excuse me if I suggest a different path, but your approach seems to be complicating your process beyond the pure simplicity that you can achieve with a centralized git repo structure and a good virtual private server.

My recommendation as far as deployment flow, at it's very basic:

- Have a central repository.
- Get ssh access to your host.
- Everyone during dev pulls from the central repository (github or bitbucket), with a certain branch (`live`, `master`, whatever) that is for code that will be deployed, everything else is dev or feature branches.
- Deployment becomes pull only.  Any changes should be done off-server or replicated off-server, and then pulled.  If you have to make hotfix commits on your live server or deploy server, that's understandable sometime, but push them back to the central repo as soon as possible, as the more you get out of sync, the more painful the eventual merge or rebase will be.
- Ideally, you'd call a deploy script to pull the latest changes from the staging/master/live branch.  Otherwise, SSH in to your box to get a simple git fast-forward checkout, and then copy those files over to a deployment location or have a simple deploy script.
- Never keep changes in the deployment, always in the repo.

Again, this requires a change of viewpoint, because switching from deploying with SFTP to ssh isn't easy, but you're already using git! so you'd probably benefit from the added flexibility and power.  If you truly can't get ssh access to your host, that'd be a *symptom* of using a non-developer friendly/underpowered host, think about the possibility of an upgrade!

Comment: thanks. I need to deploy in a single keystroke from the text editor because my modifications to the server are tested/used immediately by other developers. I use ssh for clean deployment at the end of the day and will try to respect your advice

Answer (score 1):

`git reset --hard` will undo all modifications since the last commit.

`git clean` will clean up all untracked files (not sure by you post if you need that too).

Still, must say that your workflow is a bit weird. Usually you would test your changes on your local environment or in a virtualized development environment.
Maybe you should follow Kzqai recommendations and change your workflow.